# TextView text doesn't all disappear when typing

Tags: swift, textview

I have this simple piece of code to set a placeholder, but once I enter a string, one character from said placeholder remains. This happens regardless of what I set the text to.

For example if I set the text to 'test', when I begin to enter a string all characters EXCEPT the t from test disappear. Why does that one character stick around?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.postView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    self.postView.delegate = self
    self.postView.becomeFirstResponder()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(true)
    postView.text = "\(NSDate())"
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: are you using a textview delegate of some sort? problem might be there, but without seeing any more code it's hard to tell

Comment: @Jona added in some more code.

Comment: what exactly is "postView" ?  where is it instantiated and how? why do you have viewWillAppear with the same code twice? does the locationManager have anything to do with the problem you're experiencing? you have "self.postView.delegate = self", if postView is a UITextField, can I see the delegate?

I'd like to help you out but the code you've given is not insightful enough